# Delete unused argument names in function definition(coding standards).

Tags: c++

Herb Suttter C++ coding standards says, It is good practice to delete unused argument names in functions to write zero warning program.

Example:

```
int increment(int number, int power=0){
   return number++;
}
```

should be

```
int increment(int number, int /*power*/=0){
   return number++;
}
```

If there is 'unused variable warning' to `power` argument.
This works fine for programs (no compile errors), So new function definitions will be

`int increment(int number, int =0)`

So what does `int=0` mean to compiler?

Comment: I wonder, how is that preferable to `int increment(int number, int /*power*/){return number++;}`. Without `=0` seems much more readable to me with the same effect.

Comment: @icepack: why you did not purpose to comment whole argument `int increment(int number, /*int power*/){return number++;}` (This may more clear) , but only name `int increment(int number, int /*power*/){return number++;}`.

Comment: The whole purpose of unnamed arguments is to keep the interface unchanged with the client modules. Your suggestion will break this.

Comment: I suppose that's a possible workaround for an overly fussy compiler. Without it the code is legal and well-defined. Turn off stupid warnings! (Now we'll all get to look at the outraged assertions that this warning isn't stupid but is downright useful!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unnamed formal parameter with a default value equal to 0.

First case (most popular) is an usage in `function-declaration`, something like

```
int increment(int, int = 0);
```

and in definition parameter will be named.

```
int increment(int number, int power)
{
   //
}
```

Second case is an usage for debug purposes, or for some features, that are not implemented yet, or for dummy functions.

Comment: Could you kindly explain quit more. what is the use of `Unnamed formal parameter with a default value equal to 0`. Instead of deleting whole `int power=0`

Comment: @Nayana - The function really takes two parameters, so you are allowed to write either `increment(x)` or `increment(x, 1)`. The second parameter will just be 0 if you don't supply one. This might be useful if you have old code passing two parameters and you don't want to change that. (The fact that the parameter has no name is not important if the function isn't using it anyway).

Comment: @BoPersson it's important if you don't want compiler warnings/errors regarding unused variables

Answer (score 2):

If this is a standalone function, of course, you can change method's signature commenting out last parameter

```
int increment(int number/*, int power=0*/);
```

but, you may want to keep method's signature unchanged in case:

- this is a method which is going to override a method declared in base
  class
- it is a part of module's public interface which you don't want to
  change

Also, default value for unnamed parameter can be useful when you use it in function declaration and later somewhere in cpp file you still give name to that variable.

```
// Forward declaration
int increment(int number, int =0);

// Somewhere in cpp file:
int increment(int number, int power)
  {
  return pow(number, power);
  }
```

Comment: Base class override is just a technical issue. More important is to keep the interface unchanged with the client modules.

Comment: @icepack Base class is also an Interface.

Comment: Base class **can** serve as an interface but your answer relates to the interaction between base and derived classes, not between base class and external client